# Detect if a window is using hardware-accelerated graphic context

Tags: winapi, windows-10, activex, gdi, bitblt

I'm using `BitBlt` winapi function to take a screenshot of a given window, even if the window is partially overlapped.
I have everything working fine already, except that, on Windows 10, for some windows (like the Edge browser) the screenshot turns out completely black.

A number of other questions concur on attributing this problem to the use of a hardware-accelerated graphics context on those windows.

- [BitBlt screen capture not working on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801997/)
- [Screenshot with BitBlt results in black image on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595289/)
- [Screenshot captured using BitBlt in C# results a black image on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868275/)
- [BitBlt not capturing windows in Hardware accelerated mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139903/)
- [AutoHotkey-GDIp: Capture a screenshot from a hardware accelerated window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245949/)

Apparently the GDI library is incompatible with that kind of graphics context so a different library has to be used.

My question is specifically about **how to detect if a window is using a graphics context that's incompatible with the GDI library**.

If I'm able to detect this, then I can choose which library to use for capturing the screenshot correctly (GDI, ActiveX or other).

Otherwise, the only way I could detect this is by scanning the screenshot pixel by pixel to check that's completely black. Then using a different capture method till I get some content on the screenshot.
But this sounds like an awful solution.

Comment: Take your screenshot from `GetDC(nullptr)` and then clip out the target window.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, unfortunately that technique doesn't work with partially overlapped windows.

Comment: You can't use BitBlt to capture an overlapped window in any event.

Comment: "*for some windows ... the screenshot turns out completely black*" - hardware acceleration is not the only reason that can happen. In Windows 7+, apps can simply [choose to opt-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) of their windows being rendered anywhere other than the actual display monitor (think DRM protection, for instance).

Comment: @JonathanPotter, yes, you can. That's been possible since the introduction of DWM composition in Windows Vista.

Comment: Have you tried using `PrintWindow` with `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT` as suggested in [the answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042587/536172)?

Comment: @AntonK, that looks promising. I'll try it and report back.

Comment: @AntonK, the `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT` trick is indeed able to capturing hardware-accelerated windows. Although not an answer to the question, it's a useful workaround for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

> I have everything working fine already, except that, on Windows 10,
>   for some windows (like the Edge browser) the screenshot turns out
>   completely black.

You can use [DwmRegisterThumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail)
 to capture hidden/overlapped windows, in particular UWP (like Edge, Calc, etc...)

I use it on Windows 10 without problem (+ D3D to save the bitmap)

Comment: I thought `DwmRegisterThumbnail` let you show a thumbnail in a window of yours, but it didn't give you access to the pixel data. How do you obtain the image data after calling `DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties`?

Comment: I tested with **D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile** (VS 2015, Windows 10)